# Clearfix in CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Для очистки обтекания всегда пользовался следующей записью:

```
selector:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Но сейчас часто встречаю такой вариант:

```
selector:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Хочу поинтересоваться, в чем различие между логикой работы первого и второго способа? Какие преимущества, недостатки? Почему display:table;?

Answer (score 3):

Абсолютно никакой разницы. Дело привычки. Работает и то и другое одинаково - оба очищают поток